# Getting results from specific textboxes in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass the id's of textboxes through an array index in c# so that I can get the values from the textboxes but for some reason I am unable to do it. I have almost 500 textboxes and its a data entry form.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for(int i=2;i<542;i=i+7)
{
    string a = TextBox[i].Text.ToString();
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: How do they exist on a form? As `TextBox1`, `TextBox235` and so on?

Comment: yes from TextBox1.....TextBox560

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the function `Page.FindControl()`, like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 542; i++)
{
    string val = Page.FindControl('TextBox' + i.ToString()).Text; // Or use String.Format()
}
```

Comment: If the textboxes are within server control, replace 'Page' with the server control

Comment: This works. You can also manually search the Page.Controls collection (recursively if necessary) with your own routines and check the ID property of each control you find.